# smartgwt ListGridRecord programmatically editing issue

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using smartgwt and I have a ListGrid in which I have some populated values in ListGridRecord. now if I am setting any listGridRecord Field value programmatically through setAttribute(String fieldName, String value) and refreshing the field through ListGridRecord.refreshFields(), then values get reflected to the UI. but the problem is if i am editing that same ListGridRecord by double click. then the value get lost or removed from the UI.

```
class FieldRecord extends ListGridRecord{

private int id;
private String name;

public void setID(Long id) {
  setAttribute(Constant.ID, id);
 }

public void setName(String name) {
  setAttribute(Constant.NAME, name);
 }

public Long getID() {
  return getAttribute(Constant.ID);
 }

public String getName() {
   return getAttribute(Constant.NAME); 
 }
}


class testData {
  FieldDataSource fieldDS = new FieldDataSource();

  FieldRecord fieldRec = new FieldRecord();
  //set some default value of record.

  fieldDS.addData(fieldRec);
  FieldGrid fieldGrid = new FieldGrid();
  fieldGrid.setDataSource(fieldDS);

  public void parseValue(){
  // on some condition
   fieldRec.setAttribute(Constant.NAME, "high"); 
  // programmaticaly set record value and that value is removed when i double click on 
   that record. 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the FieldGrid is a ListGrid.

You shoud use setFields to attach ListGridRecord to ListGrid

```
fieldGrid.setFields(fieldRec);
```

Try setting the ListGrid/FieldGrid's autoSaveEdits to false.

```
fieldGrid.autoSaveEdits(false);
```

**Setting autoSaveEdits false creates a "mass update" / "mass delete" interaction where edits will be retained for all edited cells** (across rows if appropriate) until ListGrid.saveEdits is called to save a particular row, or ListGrid.saveAllEdits is called to save all changes in a batch.

### Update

Use addRowEditorExitHandler  for ListGrid and explicitly set the new values like below

```
       addRowEditorExitHandler(new RowEditorExitHandler() {

          @Override
          public void onRowEditorExit(final RowEditorExitEvent event) {
            if (event.getRecord() != null) {
              Record gridRecord = event.getRecord();
              //This will be an update operations
            }
            else {
              gridRecord = new Record();
              //This will be a new record creation
            }
            if (FieldGrid.this.validateRow(event.getRowNum())) {
              for (Object attribute : event.getNewValues().keySet()) {
                //Here you will be able to see all the newly edited values
                gridRecord.setAttribute(String.valueOf(attribute),  event.getNewValues().get(attribute));
              }
//Finally you will have a record with all unsaved values.Send it to server
              addData(gridRecord);
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur reply. yeah fieldGrid refers to a ListGrid. now when i am making autoSaveEdits(false), then all the programatically set values are restoring to grid(values are getting saved to the database), but for ones which i am entering value through double click on the grid(cells are editable), that values are not getting saved or reflected(that value is shown in blue color on the UI) when i am sending my listgrid record object to server for persistence.  

if u need to know anything more about. just reply me. i will be more than happy to provide further details. Thanks @arun.

Comment: How you are sending listgridrecord to server side.I have used the addData method of ListGid.I have integrated smartgwt datasource mechanism with GWT rpc method to connect to server side.Debug and See if your edited record is reaching the server side

Comment: i have used data source to bind all the records of list grid. used addData method of DataSource. i get all the edited records of FieldGrid through FieldGrid.getRecords(). and when i debug that getRecords() method, then i am not able to see my double click edited changes.

Comment: thanks @aruns... you made my day. your solution just fits my problem. and it has been solved now. Thanks again. Big Cheers.. :)